# Applying ensemble learning to quantile regression?

Tags: boosting, quantile-regression, bagging

Is it desirable / possible to apply ensemble learning methods (boosting, bagging, etc) to the quantile regression problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and in fact this has been addressed in the literature. [Quantile random forests](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/Meinshausen06.pdf) adapt the random forest framework for quantile regression and the author provides consistency proofs. There is an R package implementing the technique as well [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantregForest/quantregForest.pdf).

In terms of desirability, ensembles will help with the bias/variance problem for quantile regression just as well as predicting the mean.

Comment: Do you have a good primer on bias/variance tradeoffs regarding quantile regression?